# ListView и обычный Activity в Android.

Tags: android, java

Ох уж эти ListView! Поищите в интернете статьи по нему, везде, обсолютно везде будут такие строки:

```
...public class ClassName extends ListActivity {...
```

Но мне нужно работать в ОБЫЧНОМ АКТИВИТИ!

```
...public class ClassName extends Activity {...
```

Мне не нужен ListActivity!  Как добиться адекватной обработки нажатия на пункт из списка? Как в *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2* добавить текст в два label'а? Повторюсь ещё раз, в **обычном активити!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите исходники `ListActivity` и вы поймёте, что это тот же `Activity` только с парочкой доп. методов.
[ListActivity.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/app/ListActivity.java?av=f). Что касается обработки нажатия кликов, вам необходимо создать обработчик `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` и установить его списку (`ListView.setOnItemClickListener`). По поводу **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2** тут зависит от того какой Adapter вы используете (`BaseAdapter`, `SimpleAdater` etc.)

Comment: Спасибо! Я использую ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Создать Объект класса ListView, назначить его видом активити (setContentView) и вместо методов класса ListActivity вызывать методы для этого ListView.